# Select joining table based on condition

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 tables

1. TableA
2. TableB
3. TableC

I need to join TableA to either with TableB or TableC based on parameters passed.
ie

```
select * from 
TableA A 
join (TableB on <Joining Condition> /  TableC on <joining condition> )
```

i tried with below query

```
select * from 
TableA A 
join (
   case when paramB<>'' then TableB on <Joining Condition>
   case when paramC<>'' then TableC on <joining condition>
 )
```

But, this is giving syntax error.
can anyone help.?

Solution:

```
create table #temp (<columns>)
if paramB<>''
begin
   select * from 
   TableA A 
   join TableB on <Joining Condition>
end
else if paramB<>''
begin
  select * from 
   TableA A 
   join TableC on <Joining Condition>
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic sql?

Comment: i don't want to use dynamic query. is there any other method..?

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql query.

Comment: you must use dynamic query

Comment: How about an if-else statement? Or do you want this in a single query?

Comment: is it possible in single query.?

Comment: As mentioned only with dynamic query you can do this.

Comment: I am inserting result of above query in #temp table. if i use if-else, in the else part it is giving an error : "#temp already exists in database".

Comment: created #temp table outside and used if-else.

Comment: Try editing your question.  Add the new IF-ELSE code and include the error message.  We should be able to help you.

Comment: The reason you cannot use a CASE in your join is because it is an expression, ie it returns a single value.  It cannot be used for control of flow, unlike other languages (where CASE is a statement instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step-1 : Create a temp table with reqd.columns
step-2 : if paramB has a value, join with TableB
         else join with TableC.

```
create table #temp (<columns>)
if paramB<>''
begin
   select * from 
   TableA A 
   join TableB on <Joining Condition>
end
else if paramB<>''
begin
 select * from 
 TableA A 
 join TableC on <Joining Condition>
end
```

Comment: Instead of simply posting code, you should attempt to explain how the code works, and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UNION ALL`.

```
select *
from a
join TableB on <join condition>
where paramB <> ''

union all

select *
from a
join TableC on <join condition>
where paramC <> ''
```

Note that `TableB` and `TableC` must have the same number of columns and have the same data type, otherwise it will produce an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
  select *
  from a 
  left join b ON <Joining Condition>
  left join c ON <Joining Condition>
  where paramB <> '' or paramC <> ''
```

Comment: Since `paramB` and `paramC` are used in `where` clause this actually behave as inner join.